# Weak derivatives of function defined over $\Bbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-derivative, distribution-theory

> Compute $D u$ in the sense of distributions, where
> $u =(x+iy)^{-1}$ is a function defined in $\mathbb{C}$ and
> $D=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial }{\partial y}$.  (Hint:  use the integration by parts
> formula)

The Solution to the question is $2\pi\delta$

I don't know how to solve it Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please read [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/418542), and `edit` your post accordingly to increase your chances of success (add context, source, definitions, attempts). Lastly, please avoid [reposting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3946220/418542).

Answer (score 1):

Show that $D\frac1{x+iy}$ is a radial distribution, with $\Phi(z)=\int_0^1 \phi(e^{2i\pi t}z)dt=\varphi(|z|^2)$ we get

$$\langle D\frac1{x+iy},\phi \rangle=
\langle D\frac1{x+iy},\Phi \rangle=-\langle \frac1{x+iy}, D\Phi\rangle$$ $$=-\int_0^\infty \frac1{re^{it}} \int_0^{2\pi}  D\Phi(re^{it}) dt rdr=-\int_0^\infty \frac1{re^{it}}  \int_0^{2\pi} \varphi'(r^2) 2re^{it} dt rdr$$ $$=-2\pi \int_0^\infty \varphi'(r^2)2rdr=2\pi \varphi(0)=2\pi \phi(0)$$